# segue to detailed Controller from Table View

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a TableViewController with cells that display the name, picture and last message between the logged in user and any other user in the app. Because a single cell is appended to only display the name of the not logged in user. The cell has both names of the logged in user and not the logged in user, so in order to display the not logged in user's name, I used this code.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MessageCell", for: indexPath) as! MessageTableViewCell

if message.ReceiverId != self.loggedInUserUid {
            var newVariable = message.ReceiverId

        if let imageName =  newVariable {

            let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(imageName)

            ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot)
                in

                if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{
                    for post in dictionary {
                        let messages = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
                        //let messages = post.value as! [String: AnyObject]
                        for (id, value) in messages {

                            self.username = messages["username"] as? String

 }}}})}}else if message.senderId != self.loggedInUserUid {
et newVariable = message.senderId

            if let imageName =  newVariable {

                let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(imageName)

                ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot)
                    in

                    if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{
                        for post in dictionary {
                            let messages = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
                       //     let messages = post.value as! [String: AnyObject] ---> very confused why it changed from post to snapshot, if I put post.value, it doesn't let me run
                            for (id, value) in messages {


                                self.username = messages["username"] as? String
```

And it displays the not logged in user's name, which is what I want, but when I segue to a new page, I also want to pass that name, depending on the cell selected.

```
override public func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {


        guard segue.identifier == "MessageNow", let chatVc = segue.destination as? SendMessageViewController else {
            return
        }
chatVc.username = self.username
}}
```

But when I click on any cell, it always displays the name of the first cell I clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need to do in prepare for segue method, you can get userName from cell which is selected and set it to chatVC

```
override public func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard segue.identifier == "MessageNow", let chatVc = segue.destination as? SendMessageViewController else {
        return
    }
    let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: selectedIndexPath) as! YourCustomCell

    chatVc.username = cell.userNameLabelPropertyOfYourCell.text
}
```

Comment: You're welcome and if you use viewcontroller "username" variable only for setting  to chatVC you can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You must assign the value to `self.username` in `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` method. The changes should reflect then.

I assume you are triggering segue on when user selects a tableView row and you are not assigning the new value to `self.username` when the user selects a tableView row, so it keeps displaying the old value.

Comment: I did the exact same thing in didSelectRowAt but it's still not working

Answer (score 0):

You could archieve this by using the 'didSelectRowAt' of the UITableViewDelegate

Try this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? MessageTableViewCell else {
         return
     }
     self.username = cell.username
}
```

Comment: cell has no property username

Comment: I edited my answer. You need to cast it to the UITableViewCell u use. (MessageTableViewCell) This cell has a property where display your username.

Comment: i mean there is no  variable in the cell called username

Comment: I thought the TableViewCell has assigned the username in the cell somewhere. Thats what you described in your question.